# Renamed files are being deleted/moved to unknown location after using os.rename()

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am currently writing a small program to rename some thousands of txt files. I wrote this code that would first create a list of files, then open each one of them, read the first 16 characters on them, and then rename each of the files according to that first word.

```
import os
path = r'/Users/myname/Documents/Corpus'
files = os.listdir(path)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    with open(file, 'r') as fo:
         str = fo.readline()
         str = r'str[0:16]'
         os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, str + '.txt'))
print index
```

However, what has been going on is that even though the code is being executed successfully - it looks like it is, since it is printing index - the files are being moved or deleted and I cannot see them or use them anymore.

Any tips on how to make it work and have the renamed files available?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: What have you done to trace the execution?  Have you tried using `locate` to find the files?  What are the arguments sent to `rename` ?

Comment: `str = r'str[0:16]'` This sets `str` to the literal string `"str[0:16]"`.

Answer (score 4):

You're renaming all your files to `str[0:16].txt`, one after the other. Consequently, all but the last of them has been deleted (when overwritten by the next file renamed to that exact same value).

Presumably, what you *intended* to do was `str = str[0:16]`, without the quotes.

<sub>(By the way, naming a variable `str` is generally a bad idea, since that's a standard type name in Python).</sub>

Comment: As in the other comment, I find this error: rename() argument 2 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str. Do you know how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the line of the file but you are re-assigning the thing you read in `str = r'str[0:16]'`. Try this:

```py
import os
path = r'/Users/myname/Documents/Corpus/'
files = os.listdir(path)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
        with open(file, 'r') as fo:
             first_chars = str(fo.readline()[:16])
             # str = r'str[0:16]'
             new_file_name = first_chars + '.txt'
             os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, new_file_name))
print index
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I encounter the following error: rename() argument 2 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str. It does rename many of the files, but many others are left unnamed - do you know why that is the case?

Comment: Maybe it is fixed now? I haven't used `os.rename()` before, but maybe it is okay now.